# How to hide cursor of an editetext after setting date using datepicker in android

Tags: android, datepicker, android-edittext

After setting the date (using datepicker) in an edittext cursor does not disapear.I want after setting the date cursor will move to next edittext.
here is my code for setting date

EditText when;
    static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

```
    private int mYear;
    private int mMonth;
    private int mDay;
//in oncreate
when = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        when.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
                return false;
            }
        });
//outside oncreate
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        }
        return null;
    }

    // updates the date in the EditText

    private void updateDisplay() {
        when.setText(new StringBuilder()
        // Month is 0 based so add 1
                .append(mDay).append("-").append(mMonth + 1).append("-").append(mYear));
    }

    // the callback received when the user "sets" the date in the dialog
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            mYear = year;
            mMonth = monthOfYear;
            mDay = dayOfMonth;
            updateDisplay();
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After set date in Edit Text use following one

when.SetFocusable(False);